# 'Variable not defined' error when changing value of checkbox.

Tags: vba, variables, excel, excel-2007

I have a simple Sub to set a checkbox (placed on a worksheet) depending on whether or not a Worksheet is protected.

`chkToggleProtect` absolutely exists, by I'm getting a compile error on either of the lines where I reference it -

> Variable not defined

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub SetToggleProtect(ByRef isprotected As Boolean)

    If isprotected Then
        chkToggleProtect.Checked = True
    Else
        chkToggleProtect.Checked = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a `Forms` checkbox or a `Controls` checkbox?

Comment: It's a `Forms` checkbox

Comment: My answer below will work. Just assign `cb.Name` properly. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is exactly the error thrown: the variable does not exist as far as this sub is concerned. Remember to fully qualify everything.

If this is a `Forms` checkbox, the following will work:

```
Private Sub CheckACheckbox(isProtected As Boolean)
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    If cb.Name = "ModifyMe" Then
        If isProtected Then
            cb.Value = True
        Else
            cb.Value = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Modify accordingly to suit.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed do the job.

Answer (score 1):

So after some giggery-pokery with the Immediate windows (my new best friend), I found that I could access the `Forms` control placed on my worksheet like this -

```
Private Sub SetToggleProtect(ByRef IsProtected As Boolean)

    If IsProtected Then
        WS.Shapes("chkToggleProtect").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
    Else
        WS.Shapes("chkToggleProtect").ControlFormat.Value = xlOff
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: :) Until literally right now, I've never really 'got' the Immediate window, using it pretty much exclusively for `Debug.Print`. Hopefully that bad boy will save me lots of headaches in the future!